# Event handler on all markers on a map - Google maps V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to attach event handlers to markers, info windows etc generically without specifying the actual variables that have been assigned individually?
WOuld save a lot of code for me and I haven't found a solution for this yet in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work(add it somewhere to your scripts):

```
  google.maps.Marker_=function(opts){
    this.clickHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(this,'click',function(){
    alert('click on a marker')
    });
    this.setOptions(opts)
  };
  google.maps.Marker_.prototype = google.maps.Marker.prototype;
  google.maps.Marker = google.maps.Marker_;
```

Comment: I was considering this solution but is there no way we could be able to attach handlers to the base marker object and detect which marker was selected without having to define a base prototype on our own? This would inconvenience me hugely because a large part of the code module has already been developed :(